# Multiple remote git operations over a single SSH session?

Tags: git, ssh

Is it possible to consolidate multiple `git` operations so that they occur over a *single* SSH session?

For example, `git fetch && git push` makes two connections to the same remote.
Is it possible to consolidate them so that they don't attempt to make more than one SSH connection?

(The above is *just an example*; there are many commands I'd like to consolidate if possible.)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bssh%5D+connection+sharing

Comment: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenSSH/Cookbook/Multiplexing

Comment: @phd: No. That reduces the number of TCP connections, not the number of times SSH has to log in and such. Also, that requires me to separately input the target server information for SSH, but git stores them locally and passes them directly, so there's some duplicate work involved there as well, which is not exactly user-friendly.

Comment: Using `ControlMaster` and `ControlPath` doesn't require multiple login attempts, or multiple uses of SSH keys or passwords.  It literally just opens a new session over the existing encrypted connection.  That's the right solution for this.

Comment: @Mehrdad No. That creates one SSH connection for every server and there is no need to login more than 1 time. Put 3 lines into config under `Host *` and they will work for any servers. Works for me perfectly for more than 10 years.

Comment: @phd, bk2202: Oh whoops, I misunderstood what it does. Okay thanks, but what should I do about the fact that I don't have the server parameters for every single repo handy? Should I write a script to extract and parse the URLs and such all manually?

Comment: `ControlPath ~/.ssh/control-%r@%h:%p`. `ssh` passes user name, host and port. One shared connection for the same 3-tuple.

Comment: @phd: Okay I just realized, so much of my confusion is due to errors in SSH (`mux_client_hello_exchange: read packet failed`, `mux_client_request_session: read from master failed: Connection reset by peer`) that seems to prevent multiplexing altogether =\ seems like this wont work...